# Call finish() inside onPause() but not when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, onpause

I have an app that needs to call finish when someone exits its main activity (so i do not want it to be **paused**), even by pressing home activity has to be finished, to handle this currently i simply call `finish()` in my `onPause()` method, since everything is done with fragments it works pretty well and gives no stability issues.

My only problem is that i cannot handle orientation changes since `onPause()` is called before `onConfigurationChanged()` (allowing me to **disable** this behavior when rotation occurs).

I could create a service that handles this but its way to complex.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to start your app at the MainActivity every time your app is launched? That is if your app is at activity B and the user press the home key, then when the app is launched again, it starts at MainActivity instead of activity B?

Comment: If `onConfigurationChanged()` is called before `onStop()` you could call `finish()` in it.

Comment: @HoanNguyen there is no activity B i have only one activity

Comment: @rciovati i want to finish() during onPause(), if i finish() on "onStop()" activity won't finish when its just paused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [onWindowFocusChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29) event instead of onPause. This function is not called when orientation changed.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Log.d(TAG, "FOCUS = " + hasFocus);
    if (!hasFocus) finish();
}
```

But note: this event is called when activity is still visible (like onPause()), you should
use onStop if you want to finish the activity when it is really and fully invisible:

```
private boolean isInFocus = false;

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Log.d(TAG, "FOCUS = " + hasFocus);
    isInFocus = hasFocus;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (!isInFocus) finish();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem - I wanted to find a way to differentiate app minimization and orientation changes.

Answer (score 3):

its simple just do:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();
        orientation = display.getOrientation();

    }
```

---

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int orientation_ = display.getOrientation();
        if (orientation_ != orientation) {
            finish();
        }
        Log.e("hello=---->", "onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems that you only have one activity, in this case you should set a flag in the manifest instead. In your MainActivity manifest add

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

Comment: Thanks Hoan, this will clear the activity on launch, but it won't finish it on exit, since i need to restart a service and free up some memory on exit i need to finish when exiting.

Comment: Why can't you call finish() in onStop()?

Comment: onStop() is not called if you just pause the activity, and i want to finish during the pause

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for orientation changes, and on the change event store a boolean value about it, like

```
boolean orientationChanging;
```

make this true when orientation is changing, and false afterwards, than in your onPause:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    if(!orientationChanging){
                finish();
            }
}
```

Comment: This won't work since onConfigurationChanged will never be called (onPause is called first).